# Compile-time warning about missing category method implementation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang, objective-c-category

In our Xcode project we have multiple targets which share some common code. Each target includes only sources which are actually used by it. So when we use some category methods inside classes which are shared between targets we need to make sure that this category implementation is also included in all targets. Xcode doesn't show any warnings during compile time or link time if we forget to include category implementation to some of the targets. And it is troublesome to do it by hand.

Is there any automated way to ensure that category implementations are included to the targets which use them?

Answer (score 2):

Categories are not automatically linked to the final binary.

They are linked if the linker finds the file where they are defined is used (which was a source of constant bug some times ago).

What you can do is use a special flag on the linker: '-all_load' and '-ObjC' in Build Settings/Linking/Other Linker flags

> -ObjC Loads all members of static archive libraries that implement an Objective-C class or category.

And from this [discussion](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2012/Apr/msg00210.html):

> -all_load and -force_load tell the linker to link the entire static archive in the final executable, even if the linker thinks that parts
>   of the archive are unused.

Another way I use to force link the module is to put a C function in the file:

```
void _linkWithNBLogClass(void)
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}
```

and call it at the start of my application:

```
 linkWithNBLogClass();
```

This way, by the console feedback, I'm sure my module is loaded and ready to be used.

Comment: This does not solve his problem, but simply makes `-respondsToSelector:` runtime safe. (If I got him correct.)

Answer (score 2):

The described behavior is as intended and much existing code would break, if it is changed.

Prior to formal protocols there was a need to declare methods without defining them. This was for optional methods, i. e. for declaring a delegate API. The usual technique was to declare a so-called [informal protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html), consisting of a category on `NSObject` that is never implemented.

But if you have a category implementation, of course the completeness of it is checked against the category interface. (Otherwise you get a "Method definition for X is not found" error.) So you do not have a missing method in the category implementation, but a missing category implementation.

I do not think that this is a big deal. You will get a runtime error instead of a compile time error and simply add the category implementation to the target.

Comment: Thanks, I see why it works this way. But I really wish there was some hack or trick or third-party script which checks this at link time.

Comment: Respectfully, I think it can be a big deal. Getting a runtime error means a crash for the user in very specific scenarios. Depending on different factors the developer might not know about it for a very long time. As the project gets more complex, with more targets and more categories, this can become an insidious source of crashes. Sadly, other than not splitting categories into separate files (where applicable), I don't know what can be done.

Comment: We are talking about a method call. Hopefully, you text every path of your software before shipping it. (Otherwise you you have bigger problems.) The "maybe some weird thing happens at runtime" is simple a myth. It is not the reason that let software crash. Have a look into your crash logs.